# Bug on delete button

Tags: vb.net

I have a delete button which is prepared to after select a row from the `Datagridview` and then press the button it will erase the column from the database. But I've just realized that an issue came through and I can't fix it. The problem is simple, after I press the button it should delete and update the `Datagridview` without what was removed, but this isn't happening. Here it is the thing, this is the code of the delete button

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
        SQLCon = New SqlConnection
        SQLCon.ConnectionString = "...."
        rbPorData.Checked = False
        rbPorExtensão.Checked = False
        rbPorNome.Checked = False
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            If MsgBox("Tem a certeza que deseja eliminar " & apagarTextBox.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    cmdDelete = "DELETE infofile WHERE Filename='" & Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "'"
                    SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(cmdDelete, SQLCon)
                    SQLDataSet = New DataSet()
                    SQLDA.Fill(SQLDataSet)
                    Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i))
                    MessageBox.Show("Ficheiro apagado com sucesso!", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Next
                SQLCon.Close()
                UpdateDeletedFiles()
                UpdateComboBoxDelete()
                MostrarResultadoTotal()
                ChangeLabelColor()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        Finally
            SQLCon.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I've made some tests. What it does is after I click on the row and press delete button it will refresh but doesn't delete on the datagridview and database. If I try again the same process it will remove. I don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
 cmdDelete = "DELETE from infofile WHERE Filename=@Filename"

 cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdDelete , SQLCon)
 cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Filename", Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() ))
 nbre = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: "nbre" is the number of rows affected by the query you can use just cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() if you want

Comment: What should I put instead of @ForDelete?

Comment: "ForDelete" is a parameter how you can name it as you like, provided that you put the same in :cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@YourVariableName", Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() ))

Comment: I've tried, but I don't think that the problem stands there. I have a dragdrop where I drop a file and the details of the that file goes to the database. The problem is there I think

Comment: @JesusDamnGod If you are using DataSets for your SQL commands, in the manner shown in your question, that could be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Do you have any ideia if it is possible using my code delete from a column and not from a row?

Comment: @JesusDamnGod I think you want to `UPDATE` rows to set the column to empty, and it will get complicated using your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you give an SQL command in a dataadapter, it is the *select* command (see [SqlDataAdapter Constructor (String, SqlConnection)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx703tc9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). That is perhaps not what you intend.

All you need to do is delete the filenames with an ordinary SQL command, something like this:

```
If MsgBox("Tem a certeza que deseja eliminar " & apagarTextBox.Text & "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

    Try
        Using sqlConn As New SqlConnection("...")
            Dim sql = "DELETE FROM infofile WHERE Filename = @Filename"
            Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Filename", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar})
                sqlConn.Open()

                For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    Dim fn = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                    sqlCmd.Parameters("@Filename").Value = fn
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next

                For i As Integer = Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                     Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Remove(Me.DataGridView2.SelectedRows(i))
                Next   

                sqlConn.Close()

            End Using

        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("Ficheiro apagado com sucesso!", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        UpdateDeletedFiles()
        UpdateComboBoxDelete()
        MostrarResultadoTotal()
        ChangeLabelColor()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try

End If
```

Comment: This works like my code works. The problem here is if I add a file and the I want to delete, it doesn't work at the first time. But if I try for the second time it works -.-

Comment: I think the problem here stands on the files that I add. Because if I add something and then reboot the app and try to delete it, it actually delete at the first attempt

Comment: Is `DataGridView2` bound to the database in any way? E.g. by setting its `.DataSource` or similar.

Comment: Make something like this?  DataGridView2.DataSource = SQLDataSet.Tables(0)

Comment: I think you might have some code operating on stale data, or not in the order you intend. If you use SQL Server Management Studio to inspect the data in the database after clicking `cmdDelete` when it appears in your program that the data has not been deleted, have the correct data been removed from the database (using the code I suggested)?

Comment: I have used your code but it does the same as mine. It doesn't delete at the first attempt

Comment: Maybe something in one of the methods UpdateDeletedFiles(), UpdateComboBoxDelete(), MostrarResultadoTotal(), or ChangeLabelColor() is interfering with the process. You are going to have to debug your program and step through it to see where things happen or do not happen.

Comment: No. Because I commented each one and it doens't work

Comment: @JesusDamnGod I edited the code to make it simpler to debug. You're going to have to do some of your own debugging investigation to check if the variables have the correct values.

Comment: I have this separated by tabs. So the first one it the add files tab and the second one is here the datagridview is. So it is possible to after add something it will update the datagridview from the other tab and show it instead of clicking on a button to displays  ?

Comment: @JesusDamnGod In that case, is your question now "How do I update one TabControl from another?" [TabControl.Selected Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) P.S. Your username might incline others to not help you. I don't care, but...